# TFS Plugin for Eclipse on Mac OX not visible as view or perspective

Tags: eclipse, plugins, tfs, macos-sierra

I'm a new Eclipse user looking to hook up Eclipse with our institutional TFS/Git environment. I'm running Mac OSX (10.12.6) and Eclipse (2019-03 (4.11.0)) and was looking to install the MS TFS plugin, using the following instructions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/java/download-eclipse-plug-in?view=azure-devops#_install-the-tee-plugin-for-eclipse

Everything goes as advertised, and I restart as directed, but I am never able to get the plugin to appear either in a View or a Perspective.  When I try to reinstall, it tells me it is already installed.

If I look in plugs tab of my workspace, I can see something like 29 TFS items installed.

Any suggestions on getting this into a useable state (i.e., as a view or perspective) would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Al

Comment: What do you mean by _either in a View or a Perspective_? Did you looked into _Window > Show View > Other..._ and _Window > Perspective > Open Perspective > Other..._?

Comment: Sorry, yes, that's exactly what I did.

Comment: I should add that when I look at Installation Details under "About Eclipse" I see "Team Explorer Everywhere" listed under "installed software."  However, it doesn't appear under the "plug-ins" tab of the same dialogue.

Comment: Another update - now that I've learned where the error log is, I did indeed find errors (here's a small sample):

SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse 2 0 2019-04-17 20:54:43.004
!MESSAGE Failed to find a configured bundleInfo for: [R]com.microsoft.tfs.checkinpolicies 14.134.0.201804261732.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse 2 0 2019-04-17 20:54:43.004
!MESSAGE Failed to find a configured bundleInfo for: [R]com.microsoft.tfs.checkinpolicies.build 14.134.0.201804261732.